# Set position of InfoTip

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7

My TListView control has `ShowHints` enabled and handles the `OnInfoTip` event. The message in the popup InfoTip box is set in the `OnInfoTip` handler. However, the position of the popup InfoTip box is relative to the position of the mouse when hovering over an item in the list. There doesn't appear to be a way to customise the position.

Is it possible set the position of the hint popup, for example in a specific area of the TListView or even elsewhere on the form outside the bounds of the TListView control? Ideally, I'd like to display the hint popup in such a way to minimise (or eliminate) obscuring any other item in the TListView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to expose the CMHintShow of the TListView as following:

```
  type
   TListView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView)
      private
         FPos: TPoint;
      protected
         procedure CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
      published
         property MyPos: TPoint  read FPos write FPos;
   end;


  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    ...
    ListView1: TListView;
```

Then at the OnInfoTip event you set the desired Position. At my example, I get the coords of the TopLeft Corner of a ScrollBox (sbxFilter - which is located under the TlistView) and pass the Coords to the TListView property MyPos.

```
procedure TfrmMain.ListView1InfoTip(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; var InfoTip: string);
var
   p: TPoint;
begin
   InfoTip := 'Test';
   p := sbxFilter.ClientToScreen(point(0, 0));
   ListView1.MyPos := p;
end;


{ TListView }

procedure TListView.CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow);
begin
   inherited;
   Message.HintInfo.HintPos := FPos;
end;
```

Comment: This works nicely. I named my TListView sub-class `THintPostListView` and put the declaration and functions in a separate base unit so that any form can use the control as required. At the top of a form using the control simply declare `TListView = class(THintPosListView);` as in this example.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to display the hint, that you define in the `OnInfoTip()` event in e.g. a `StatusPanel` of a `StatusBar` (at the bottom of the form).

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1InfoTip(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  var InfoTip: string);
begin
  InfoTip := '';
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'ListView Infotip, Item '+IntToStr(Item.Index);
end;
```

Comment: Nice, simple solution! Does require unused space somewhere on the form to display the hint details, though.